# ERROR | Failed to load json schema! java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Tags: java, json, json-schema-validator

I am trying to validate a json object against its schema and my schema file is very big (386 lines).

This is my lines of code in java:

```
public static void jsonSchemValidator() throws Exception {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();;


        InputStream jsonStream = inputStreamFromClasspath("/json/pickevent1.json");
        InputStream schemaStream = inputStreamFromClasspath("/json/schemaeg.json");

        JsonNode json = objectMapper.readTree(jsonStream);
        JsonNode jsonSchema = objectMapper.readTree(schemaStream);
        JsonSchemaFactory validatorFactory = JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(SpecVersionDetector.detect(jsonSchema));
        JsonSchema schema = validatorFactory.getSchema(schemaStream);
        Set<ValidationMessage> validationResult = schema.validate(json);
        if (validationResult.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("no validation errors :-)");
        } else {
            validationResult.forEach(vm -> System.out.println(vm.getMessage()));
        }
        jsonStream.close();
        schemaStream.close();
    }
}
```

The code for IndputStream:

```
  public static InputStream inputStreamFromClasspath(String path) {
        return Utils.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
    }
```

The above works well for small schema. But it gives an error of:

```
ERROR | Failed to load json schema!
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
ERROR | Failed to load json schema!
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:170)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:336)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.ensureLoaded(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:539)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.detectEncoding(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:133)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.constructParser(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:256)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory._createParser(JsonFactory.java:1655)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:1083)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:3056)
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaFactory.getSchema(JsonSchemaFactory.java:315)
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaFactory.getSchema(JsonSchemaFactory.java:324)
    at common.Utils.jsonSchemValidator(Utils.java:105)
    at picking.begin.TestAssertionForPickBegin.before(TestAssertionForPickBegin.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:529)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:497)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:110)
com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaFactory.getSchema(JsonSchemaFactory.java:319)
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaFactory.getSchema(JsonSchemaFactory.java:324)
    at common.Utils.jsonSchemValidator(Utils.java:105)
    at picking.begin.TestAssertionForPickBegin.before(TestAssertionForPickBegin.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:529)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:497)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:110)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:170)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:336)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.ensureLoaded(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:539)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.detectEncoding(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:133)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.constructParser(ByteSourceJsonBootstrapper.java:256)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory._createParser(JsonFactory.java:1655)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:1083)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:3056)
    at com.networknt.schema.JsonSchemaFactory.getSchema(JsonSchemaFactory.java:315)
    ... 26 more
```

I am quite new to java. Any suggestions will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: post also the code for `inputStreamFromClasspath`. If you use `class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream`, you must omit the initial slash: `json/schemaeg.json`

Comment: @cucaracho updated the code

Comment: yep, try removing the initial `/`

Comment: @cucaracho  I removed the initial / but its throws 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument "in" is null
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._assertNotNull

Comment: are your jsons in `src/main/resources` ?

Comment: @cucaracho it is in  src/test/resources

Comment: so the code is a unit test, right? Does `Utils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path)` work?

Comment: @cucaracho no its still the same with Utils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path). It is the same exception: ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument "in" is null at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._assertNotNull

Comment: @cucaracho with Utils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path) and I removed the initial / the error is same: ERROR | Failed to load json schema!
java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Comment: post the stacktrace

Comment: Posted @cucaracho

Comment: try removing `        jsonStream.close();
        schemaStream.close();`

Comment: @cucaracho I removed it, it is the same error ERROR | Failed to load json schema!
java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Comment: this needs to be stepped through with a debugger

Comment: @cucaracho the problem is its working for small schema file and its breaking for JsonSchema schema = validatorFactory.getSchema(schemaStream); this is where its throwing exception of Stream close, is there any reference for json schema validator which can work for big schema files?

Comment: I don't think it's the size. Looks like `objectMapper.readTree(schemaStream);` closes  `schemaStream` so `validatorFactory.getSchema(schemaStream);` fails because it's already closed. Streams can't be read multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are reading from the InputStream `schemaStream` twice.

You pass it first to `objectMapper.readTree(...)`, and later on, you pass the same InputStream to `validatorFactory.getSchema(...)`.

In general, doing this is a bad thing, because the first use of the stream may leave it exhausted (i.e. it has no more data to return) or closed, as it seems happens in your case.  If I'm honest, I'm surprised that you don't get similar behaviour with small schemas: I guess this is a quirk of the InputStream that gets returned from a call to `.getResourceAsStream(...)`.

Try opening a new InputStream from the resource rather than attempting to read from one for the second time.  I've also adjusted your code to use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), so that the InputStreams get closed even in the event of an exception being thrown:

```java
public static void jsonSchemValidator() throws Exception {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try (InputStream jsonStream = inputStreamFromClasspath("/json/pickevent1.json")) {
        JsonNode json = objectMapper.readTree(jsonStream);
        JsonSchemaFactory validatorFactory;
        try (InputStream schemaStream = inputStreamFromClasspath("/json/schemaeg.json")) {
            JsonNode jsonSchema = objectMapper.readTree(schemaStream);
            validatorFactory = JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(SpecVersionDetector.detect(jsonSchema));
        }

        try (InputStream schemaStream = inputStreamFromClasspath("/json/schemaeg.json")) {
            JsonSchema schema = validatorFactory.getSchema(schemaStream);
            Set<ValidationMessage> validationResult = schema.validate(json);
            if (validationResult.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("no validation errors :-)");
            } else {
                validationResult.forEach(vm -> System.out.println(vm.getMessage()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```